# Close other HTML window by function

Tags: javascript, popup

I need a popup window to appear to the user but without a parent window. However, I believe this to be impossible.

I think that I may have to make the popup close the parent after it appears, but how?

iI tried this in the popup:

```
<BODY align="center" valign="center" onload="javascript:window.opener='x';window.close();">
```

But it closed the popup window itself. How can I make the popup close its parent?

Comment: If you need to close the parent and show only the popup, why dont you just directly forward to popup URL in main window and resize the browser if needed?

Comment: @josek - **never** resize the browser, most prevent this for good reason.  What right does your page have to resize the other 12 tabs I have open?

Comment: @Nick Craver - youre right. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `window.opener.close()` instead.

Comment: thank you all 

"klausbyskov" , it works when i try your answer but i dont want the warning, how can i work without it?

Comment: @lusey - You can't, no offense but it's there to protect the user against things just like you're doing.

Comment: what I am trying to do is nothing but closing the window that I opened :/

Answer (score 0):

Unless the "parent window" was opened with JavaScript itself, then that is not possible. JavaScript is only allowed to close windows it opened itself.